# Referencing time and (time+10 seconds) to calc normalized price return in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to normalize price at a certain point in time with respect to price 10 seconds later using this formula:  `((price(t+10seconds) – price(t)) / price(t) ) / spread(t)`

Both price and spread are columns in my dataframe. And I have indexed my dataframe by timestamp (pd.datetime object) because I figured that would make calculating price(t+10sec) easier.

What I've tried so far:

```py
pos['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(pos['timestamp'])
pos.set_index('timestamp')

def normalize_data(pos):
    
    t0 = pd.to_datetime('2021-10-27 09:30:13.201')
    x = pos['mid_price'] 
    y = ((x[t0 + pd.Timedelta('10 sec')] - x)/x) / (spread)
    return y

pos['norm_price'] = normalize_data(pos)
```

this gives me an error because I'm indexing `x[t0+pd.Timedelta('10sec')]` but not the other x's in the equation. I also don't think I'm using `pd.Timedelta` or the `x[t0+pd.Time...]` correctly and unsure of how to fix all this/define a better function.

Any input would be much appreciated

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MX5Kx.jpg)

Comment: Two suggestions for this (or future) questions, to help make it easier for people to provide you with answers: 1) be sure to provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- your code snippet above will fail to run because `spread` was never defined, and 2) you state that your code "gives me an error" but please tell people *what the actual error message was*, since that is a huge help in figuring out why the code fails to run.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

`pos.set_index('timestamp')`

This line of code will *return a new dataframe, and leave your original dataframe unchanged*. So, your function `normalize_data` is working on the original version of `pos`, which does not have the index you want, and neither will `x`. Change your code to this:

`pos = pos.set_index('timestamp')`

And that should get things working.